# Electrical water fountain - what is its power consumption?

Tags: batteries, power-consumption

[image: Photo of electrical water fountain]

Above is the image of the electrical water fountain given to me by my ex-employer, on account of my birthday. The single LED changes its colour (Red, Green, Blue) every two seconds. It is operated by 230 V AC mains.

1. How to calculate the power consumption of this product?
2. Can the water fountain be modified to work on batteries (DC) instead of AC?
3. What will be the electrical circuit modification in the product if the single led is to be displayed every two seconds in 10 different colours viz Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Violet, Indigo, Cyan, Pink, White & Black?

Comment: Google says "404. That’s an error. The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

Comment: https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipO0S0jscVM220tR7-UUXyzeo47VSMSXJWI-Fe_K product image link is working. Thanks.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar The link isn't working for me either.  You'd have to measure the power consumption with an AC power analyzer (to get real power) and it's unlikely the same motor would run on batteries.  You could use an inverter to get AC from batteries but the efficiency would be poor.  You'd be much better off getting a DC powered pump

Comment: Please include the photo in your post so that we don't have to follow links to understand your question.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/prashantsadanandakerkar/ https://www.instagram.com/p/CDZZZUmpspN/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link I have also uploaded the product image on instagram site now. Are this links working? Thanks.

Comment: As explained, you should include the picture in your post, not as a link. Sphero has fixed for you.

Comment: Never calculate power consumption for something sitting right in front of you. Measure it instead. OK. Maybe "never"  is too strong a word. But you should measure it anyway, even if you calculate it also, just to be sure. Too many variables to trust a calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The item in question appears to have a color-changing LED and a water pump. The LED will be, likely by far, the lesser of the two energy-consuming items in the device.

The easiest way to determine the power consumption maximum is to refer to the nameplate, typically on the bottom, which should give an upper bound on the power consumption. If is is powered by a wall-wart type device that nameplate estimate from the wall wart may be several times the actual consumption.

Second easiest (and most accurate) way is to measure it using an inexpensive plug-in meter device such as the Kill-a-Watt or similar clone devices available from China suppliers.

If it has a wall-wart and is powered by DC you could use a multimeter to measure the DC power consumption and then add 25 or 30% for the wall wart inefficiency.

I think you could certainly have it run from batteries but not for long on a small battery.

Comment: My Kill-a-Watt can't read anything close to that little power; wants a few watts min...

Comment: I’m guessing 5-10W for the pump and power supply losses.